# NullPointerException using WebDriverWait Boolean

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have two classes, one that runs the methods to click on buttons etc. On the page, there is a button that is disabled and I have a WebDriverWait to wait for it to be enabled again by checking that the attribute "disabled" has been removed from the html element. However, when I run the test I get a nullPointerException. I think I know where it's coming from but having a problem trying to work a way around it.

This is the method that runs to get to perform the actions:

```
public void methodThatRuns(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
    properties.inputTxt(driver, "100");
    sundries.waitEnabledButton(driver, properties.nextButton(driver));
    properties.nextButton(driver).click();
}
```

This is the waitEnabledButton method from another class that it calls to wait:

```
public void waitEnabledButton(WebDriver driver, final WebElement btn) throws NullPointerException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    System.out.println("Starting the wait");
    try {
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                final String attribute = btn.getAttribute("disabled");
                if (attribute.equals(null)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        System.out.println("The disabled attribute was destroyed successfully and the script can continue."); //using this as the attribute gets destroyed when the button is enabled which throws a staleElement exception
    } 
    System.out.println("Wait is over");
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 if (attribute.equals(null)) {
    return true;
  }`
```

If attribute is null then .equals call will lead to NPE.  Try with attribute == null.

Comment: That fixed my problem! So simple, yet so brilliant! Thanks for that!